# Why doesn't Nokogiri load the full page?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm using Nokogiri to open Wikipedia pages about various countries, and then extracting the names of these countries in other languages from the interwiki links (links to foreign-language wikipedias). However, when I try to open [the page for France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France), Nokogiri does not download the full page. Maybe it's too large, anyway it doesn't contain the interwiki links that I need. How can I force it to download all?

Here's my code:

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + country_name
page = nil
begin
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rescue   OpenURI::HTTPError=>e
  puts "No article found for " + country_name
end

language_part = page.css('div#p-lang')
```

Test:

```
with country_name = "France"
=> []

with country_name = "Thailand"
=> really long array that I don't want to quote here,
   but containing all the right data
```

Maybe this issue goes beyond Nokogiri and into OpenURI - anyway I need to find a solution.

Comment: Did you know that open() is not Nokogiri?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nokogiri does not retrieve the page, it asks OpenURI to do it with an internal `read` on the StringIO object that Open::URI returns.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'zlib'

stream = open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France')
if (stream.content_encoding.empty?)
  body = stream.read
else
  body = Zlib::GzipReader.new(stream).read
end

p body
```

Here's what you can key off of:

```
>> require 'open-uri' #=> true
>> open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France').content_encoding #=> ["gzip"]
>> open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thailand').content_encoding #=> []
```

In this case if it's `[]`, AKA "text/html", it reads. If it's `["gzip"]` it decodes.

Doing all the stuff above and tossing it to:

```
require 'nokogiri'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
language_part = page.css('div#p-lang')
```

should get you back on track.

Do this after all the above to confirm visually you're getting something usable:

```
p language_part.text.gsub("\t", '')
```

See Casper's answer and comments about why you saw two different results. Originally it looked like Open-URI was inconsistent in its processing of the returned data, but based on what Casper said, and what I saw using curl, Wikipedia isn't honoring the "Accept-Encoding" header for large documents and returns gzip. That is fairly safe with today's browsers but clients like Open-URI that don't automatically sense the encoding will have problems. That's what the code above should help fix.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented this and now I'm getting data. The only problem is that Unicode country names are not showing up correctly anymore, e. g. I'm getting αñ½αñ╝αÑìαñ░αñ╛αñ¿αÑìαñ as France's Hindi name. This is only a problem with the gzip-encoded names, the others are automatically correct. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: just do page = Nokogiri::HTML(body, nil, 'UTF-8') instead.

Comment: Rather than assume it is "UTF-8", you might want to use the response's `external_encoding` method. Assuming UTF-8 with one site consistently is pretty safe but if you are looking at multiple sites you might get incompatible encodings. Just something to consider.

Comment: All hail the Tin Man! :D

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of head scratching the problem is here:

```
> wget -S 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France'
Resolving en.wikipedia.org... 91.198.174.232
Connecting to en.wikipedia.org|91.198.174.232|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
  Content-Language: en
  Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 23:31:36 GMT
  Content-Encoding: gzip <<<<------ BINGO!
  ...
```

You need to unpack the gzipped data, which open-uri does not do automatically.
Solution:

```
def http_get(uri)
  url = URI.parse uri

  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |h|
    h.get(url.path)
  }

  headers = res.to_hash
  gzipped = headers['content-encoding'] && headers['content-encoding'][0] == "gzip"
  content = gzipped ? Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(res.body)).read : res.body

  content
end
```

And then:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(http_get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"))
```

Comment: Actually, Open::URI does decode gzip, but appears to do so for pages under a certain size. All the results from Wikipedia are gzipped however the page for France isn't decoded. The page from Thailand, which is smaller, is decoded.

Comment: Uh..not on my machine. Thailand is not gzipped when I request it. It seems to depend on your location or perhaps which wikipedia server you happen to hit. With wget -S Thailand is not gzipped for me. Also looking at the code for open-uri I couldn't find a location where it would unpack packed pages...are you sure it does this?

Comment: @Tin Man, you are wrong. The problem is wikipedia seems to compress the page when the page is too large, even if an Accept-Encoding header is not present in the request. Here's a small 2.7k page that you can test this with. open-uri does NOT decode it properly:  open('http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/', "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip").read.

Comment: I might be wrong about Wikipedia, but that is a red-herring. The issue was to get Open-URI results decoded correctly, which is the OPs concern.

Comment: Yes ok..sure..just don't think that open-uri is able to decode gzip. It is not. Even if it's a 10 byte page, it won't decode it. The reason your example works is that open-uri by default does not send an Accept-Encoding header, hence most webservers just return text/html. Once the page gets too big SOME servers seem to compress the page anyway, disregarding the missing Accept-Encoding..and that's when open-uri fails. Anyway..your solution works, but not because of the reason you thought.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'zlib'

open('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate') do |response|
  if response.content_encoding.include?('gzip')
    response = Zlib::GzipReader.new(response)
    response.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |name|
      to_io.public_send(name)
    end
  end

  yield response if block_given?

  response
end
```